# log4net RollingFileAppender with logger name as prefix for filename

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, rollingfileappender

I have multiple loggers and I want to prefix file names by the name of the logger, using `RollingLogFileAppender`. With the below configuration I'm stuck with the static file name `logger_2016-06-06.log` - the logger name is not resolved correctly and instead static prefix logger is always used.

However in the contents of the log file I do get the `%logger` value correctly as specified in the `appender/layout/conversionPattern` section.

This is my configuration:

```
<log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
            <conversionPattern value="App_Data\log\%logger_" />
        </file>
        <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
        <staticLogFileName value="false" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

Comment: have you done a google search or looked at documentation and or Tips and Tricks when using FileAppender...? http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2009/03/03/tips-on-using-log4net-rollingfileappender.aspx

Comment: Of course I did. Thanks for the link, but somehow I don't see anything there that would help me solving my problem.

Comment: Appenders are shared between loggers. If you want each logger to write to a different file, then each logger needs it's own appender.